# grub: What is a menu item identifier?

Tags: linux, grub

When setting the default grub entry a tool you can use is `grub-set-default`.

`grub-set-default` specifies three ways to target a default - taken from its [manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man8/grub-set-default.8.html):

```
MENU_ENTRY is a number, a menu item title or a menu item identifier.
```

The first two I know about, but I see some limitations using them in some cases:

**Number**:

As I understand it the `number` is the index the `menuentry` has, so if you install a new kernel the position it gets is not always consistent across systems, because it depends on which and how many kernels are installed.

**Menu item title**

The full title of the `menuentry` which varies depending on the system language set when generating the config.
For instance this is what I have on one machine whose language is set to Danish:

`Ubuntu, med Linux 5.4.0-99-generic`.

Since it's language setting dependent it doesn't seem ideal, for multiple machines whose languages may vary.

---

So my two-fold question is:

1. What is a `menu item identifier`?
2. Can one predict before installation what identifier a newly installed kernel would have? Is it consistent regardless of language setting and what other kernels are installed?

Answer (score 0):

> What is a menu item identifier?

I seem to have stumbled onto the right answer to the question above. Given the Grub menu (as described in /boot/grub/grub.cfg) shown below, the menu item identifier for the last item in the submenu is `'gnulinux-advanced-79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04>gnulinux-5.4.0-109-lowlatency-advanced-79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04'`

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04
        fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-40-generic root=UUID=79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-40-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-40-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.13.0-40-generic-advanced-79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 5.13.0-40-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-40-generic root=UUID=79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-40-generic
        }
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-40-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.13.0-40-generic-recovery-79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 5.13.0-40-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-40-generic root=UUID=79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-40-generic
        }
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-109-lowlatency' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.4.0-109-lowlatency-advanced-79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt2'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 5.4.0-109-lowlatency ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-109-lowlatency root=UUID=79ff4213-58cc-4410-9b21-b6db63e1da04 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-109-lowlatency
        }
     
        [...]
}
```